# Identify active image in jcarousel - views slideshow

Tags: javascript, views

Is it possible to highlight the current active image in jCarousel thumbnail pager combined with views slideshow image?

I have setup views_slideshow and added a views_slideshow_jcarousel pager. I see there is an active class on one of the carousel images, but I can't seem to use it. I can only affect the first image in the list with css like:

```
.views_slideshow_active_pager_field_item { opacity: 0.5; }
.jcarousel-item-horizontal .active { opacity: 0.5; }
```

For example...add opacity to the active image select below:
[image]

Comment: You should be able to see the active class on active image. Try using firebug.

Comment: Solved... It was my lack of CSS understanding. Jcarousel set the class on the active pager item. I had to specify active class with item class, without a space and added the img tag to work.

    .jcarousel-item.actve img{ opacity: 0.5; }